# Why are the "srcset" and "sizes" attributes in the "img" element not working the way they should?

Tags: html

I am struggling to understand the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes in the `<img>` tag.

First of all, why is my code not working?

```
<img src="orange.jpg" alt="orange" srcset="coffee.jpg 600w, mycat.jpg 800w" sizes="(max-width:500px) 600px, 800px">
```

When i run this code, the **mycat.jpg** image loads regardless of how much i shrink the browser. Why?

I thought this code is supposed to mean that, if the viewport is up to *500px*, then the *600px* image should load, which is the coffee image, and if there isn't one, then the *800px* image should load, which is the mycat image. So why is the mycat image loading regardless of the viewport?

Also, if the browser chooses which `srcset` image to load depending on the proximity of the sizes, then in what case does the `src` image (orange) loads?

Also, what happens if i add a wrong number for the resolution size of each `srcset` image? In my example, I've described **coffee** image as `600w` and **mycat** image as `800w`. What if these numbers are wrong?

Another thing I struggle to understand is, why is the `sizes` attribute being used here for adding a *media condition*? Isn't that what the `media` attribute is for?

The explanation given in **mozilla.developers.org** and other websites is atrocious. Please do not copy-paste any external sources purporting to explain this. They do not. I've seen them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because your code is incorrect because if you wanna put `srcset` attribute then you have to put it inside `source` tag which should be inside `picture tag` tag. Try writing the code attached below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>srecset attribute</title>
</head>
<body>
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:800px)" srcset="mycat.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:600px)" srcset="coffee.jpg">
  <img src="orange.jpg" alt="orange" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code if the screen resolution/size is more than **800px** then **mycat.jpg** will be displayed.

If screen resolution/size is between **600px** to **800px** then **coffee.jpg** will be displayed.

And If screen resolution/size is less than **600px** then **orange.jpg** will be displayed.

And if this doesn't work comment your issue, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: I am not asking about the picture element, but the srcset used in the img element. Read my question again. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img 

I am learning about the srcset and sizes attributes OF THE IMG ELEMENT. Not picture element.

Comment: @IloveCoffee The code might be not working because many browsers do not support some tags and attributes that might be one of the reasons and the other reason would be in which version of HTML you're coding because HTML5 has removed many tags. So, check both the cases. And the thing you're trying to do, it's most popular and common method is by using `<picture>` tag.

Comment: @IloveCoffee Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Comment: I've asked another person who does responsible pages about this issue, and i am still waiting for an answer. I can't say whether you've helped me out or not, since both developer.mozilla and w3schools says that the attributes should be working. I don't know how to verify if they aren't working anymore, or if the issue is in my code.

Comment: @IloveCoffee Can you do me a favour that whenever your issue is solved please comment and let me know how it is solved. I would love to know how your issue is solved.

Comment: @IloveCoffee I wanted to know whether your issue was solved or not, I am eagerly waiting to know how you solved it.

Comment: No, i haven't heard from that guy yet. At this point, i have no other option but to move on with other problems, and leave this one aside. I will give you the best answer since you were the most engaged, and plus it's likely that these tags aren't used anymore, or if they are, very rarely.

Comment: @IloveCoffee Sad to hear that your issue is not solved but can you do me a favour by upvoting my answer if it helped you even a bit, I know you have alredy accepted my answer but i'm just tryna grow on stack overflow  and thanks for accepting my answer, it means a lot to me.

Comment: @IloveCoffee Thanks for accepting and upvoting my answer you have made my day. I hope to get more chances to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the image and sources inside a picture tag.

```html
<picture>
<source srcset="coffee.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width:500px)">
<source srcset="mycat.jpg 800w" sizes="(max-width:600px)">
<img src="orange.jpg" alt="orange">
</picture>
```

Comment: I'm asking about the "img" element, not the "picture" element. Please read my question again, carefully.

Comment: it doesn't work for the image element, but it will if you put your image element inside the picture element and add sources.

Answer (score 0):

When browsers evaluate srcset, they take more than the sizes attribute into account. While I'm not sure the full list of things they consider, I know they also consider screen pixel density.

In your example, if the browser detects a 2x or higher pixel density, it would attempt to load a 1200px image to fulfill the 600px size. Since no such size exists, it uses the largest image available: mycat.jpg.